# Copying and pasting org tables misaligned?

Tags: org-mode, org-table

I have a table in Org mode that looks as shown below

```
| S.No. | Template       | V800A | V800B |
|-------+----------------+-------+-------|
|    1. | IFD03B         |    17 |     8 |
|    2. | Calcs          |     5 |     5 |
|    3. | ALM_4S_AX04B   |    20 |    16 |
|    4. | ALM_DX05B      |     7 |     2 |
|    5. | ALM_1S_HZD05B  |     2 |     1 |
|    6. | ALM_RERING03B  |     4 |     4 |
|    7. | ALM_DI_DO05B   |    17 |    16 |
|    8. | IS04B          |     2 |     2 |
|    9. | Step06B        |    12 |    14 |
|   10. | DO_INDEPEND06B |     8 |     8 |
|   11. | AO_PID13_01B   |     5 |     5 |
|-------+----------------+-------+-------|
|       | Total          |    99 |    81 |
```

But when I paste this content within MS Outlook or MS Excel it looks as shown below.

[image]

Why does this behave in such a manner and what should I do to fix this?
Presently, I'm using `Text to Columns` option (in MS Excel) to convert this into a table and deleting the `|` and it makes a clean excel table.
For Outlook, I do not have such options to exercise.
Are there any settings to be made into Emacs to fix this?

P.S:  I'm on Windows 7 with Emacs 24.5.1 installed. I will attempt this on Ubuntu (+open office) and update the question later.

Comment: Really simple method no effort 1- select table 2- menu - Tbl - export to file .csv
3- open the file in excel Thanks to Alejandro C.

Answer (score 4):

You probably want to use `org-table-export` which will take the table under the point and export it to a Tab separated file (which is then easy to copy and paste into excel).

You could try wrapping it for convenience. For example:

```
(defun copy-table-as-tsv ()
(interactive)
(unless (org-at-table-p)
(user-error "No table at point"))
(let ((table (org-table-to-lisp
    (buffer-substring-no-properties (org-table-begin)  (org-table-end)))))
(kill-new (orgtbl-to-tsv table '()))))
```

Comment: +1 for the good idea - i learnt this thing new. But I'd not prefer this method for smaller tables. Its not worth the effort - I think.

Comment: You could try wrapping it for convenience. For example: `(defun copy-table-as-tsv ()
    (interactive)
  (unless (org-at-table-p) (user-error "No table at point"))
  (lexical-let ((table (org-table-to-lisp (buffer-substring-no-properties
                                           (org-table-begin)
                                           (org-table-end)))))
    (kill-new (orgtbl-to-tsv table '()))))`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `org` is using space characters for whitespace in the table, and is assuming that you're using a monospace font.  If you look closely at your screenshot, you can see that it's using a non-monospace font.

Your simplest option to cut-and-paste into something like Outlook or Word would be to select the pasted table and change it's font to something monospaced, such as Courier New.

Comment: You may be right. I will try to replace the font type to mono-space fonts. I tried using the copy-paste method with Excel and Word 2016 - It does paste the text using mono-space fonts.